# how to divide big numbers of table rows into parts or slider

Tags: html, slider, divide

I have a [report page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwhRo.jpg) witch get data from big table contain more than 1000 rows how to divide this report into parts or slider like mail box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this approach: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html#)

And here is a demo:

**LIBRARIES**

[jquery 1.11.0](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js)

[jquery.dataTables.css](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css)

[jquery.dataTables.min.js](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').dataTable();
} );
```

**CSS**

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 3em;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Find it entirely on the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eapsxqa/3/)